# How to associate a heading/document title with an accordion button

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Obligatory 'I have googled but am stuck'. I have a number of documents on a page with associated collapsible 'More Info' accordions. I want to be able to report on when people click to open one of these accordions and what the corresponding document name is.

Implementing tracking in GTM to show opens on the accordions are not a problem, but how do I associate the document name (h4) with the click event?

Div containing document, document heading and associated 'More Info':
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIFOC.png)

Div that the document heading and the more info button are in:

```
<div class="employee-comms-results-documents">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 no-padding-right no-padding-left">
<div>
<div class="primary-document-meta"><div class="doc-type-pill" id="doc-type-pill-Flyers">Flyers
    </div>
</div>
<h4>Helping you save for retirement</h4>
<div class="secondary-document-meta"><a href="#" class="btn-moreinfo" data-reveal="slide-54">More info <span class="caret"></span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would need to see the whole site structure to be sure, but for your example I created a JavaScript variable in GTM that returns the corresponding h4-text on click.

This code has worked for me:

```
function(){
  var clickElement = jQuery({{Click Element}}).parent(".secondary-document-meta").parent("div").find("h4").text();
  return clickElement;
}
```